# Check if Javascript array values are in ascending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Say I have an array of integers in Javascript, that I would like to check if all of its values are in ascending order. What i want is to save the array key in another array in case the algorithm finds a value that is lower (or equal) not only comparing the immediate previous one, but also comparing any value that is before it.
What I did was this:

```
arr = [], nonvalid = [];

for (var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
    if ( arr[j+1] <= arr[j] ){
        nonvalid.push(j);
    }
}
```

Obviously the above algorightm checks only for values that are lower comparing the one before it.

An array might contain values like these:

arr = 1, 2, 3, 10, **5**, 11, 12, **2**, **4**, 25

The non valid values are the bold ones. If I run the above loop, it won't "catch" the second last one (**4**), because it's higher than its *closest left brother*, but not that high than its all *left brothers*.

**EDIT:**

Tried the following solutions and none return all the nonvalid values for this array except mine . :(

They returned the last two values correctedly, but not the second one.
I don't understand why though.

[24398, **24397**, 25004, 25177, 26302, 28036, 29312, 29635, 29829, 30476, 32595, 33732, 34995, 36047, 36363, 37310, 38022, 38882, 40746, 41212, 42846, 43588, 44029, 44595, 44846, 45727, 46041, 47293, 48002, 48930, 49858, 51184, 51560, 53895, 54247, 54614, 55713, 56813, 57282, 57480, 57875, 58073, 58403, 60321, 61469, 62051, 62310, 62634, 63217, 64505, 65413, 65677, 65940, 66203, 66572, 67957, 68796, 68964, 69098, 69233, 69435, 69759, 71496, 72577, 72823, 73007, 73252, 73743, 73866, 76405, 77037, 77416, 77669, 79691, 80885, 81339, 81794, 82067, 82431, 83244, 84861, 86836, 88632, 89877, 90296, 91049, 91885, 92351, 92614, 93141, 93733, 93930, 94531, 95206, 95882, 96895, 97732, 97973, 99261, 99422, 99583, 100332, 100599, 101666, 102066, 102600, 103504, 104432, 105174, 107216, 109085, 110181, 110679, 111177, 111988, 112553, 113005, 113457, **600**, **600**]

Comment: So could you keep track of a max value?

Comment: max value ah? Interesting! Let me try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you find an element out of order, look at the next elements until they are no longer out of order relative to the element **before** the out of order one.

Add the out of order elements to the second array and continue from the new in order element.

```
var outs= [], L= A.length, i= 0, prev;
while(i<L){
    prev= A[i]; 
    while(A[++i]<prev) outs.push(i);
}
alert(outs)
```

Comment: Wow! A sophisticated and a laconic one :) Works like a charm. And it seems to be less demanding than other solutions.

Answer (score 10):

One other very nice functional way of doing this could be;

```js
var isAscending = a => a.slice(1)
                        .map((e,i) => e > a[i])
                        .every(x => x);
                        
console.log(isAscending([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(isAscending([1,2,5,4]));
```

Nice code but there are redundancies in it. We can further simplify by consolidating `.map()` and `.every()` into one.

```js
var isAscending = a => a.slice(1)
                        .every((e,i) => e > a[i]);
                        
console.log(isAscending([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(isAscending([1,2,5,4]));
```

Comment: Real nice solution

Comment: That's a good piece of code. FYI, it does works for string too.

Answer (score 9):

Keep track of the largest value you have seen ([see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CWu4b/)):

```
function find_invalid_numbers(arr) {
    var nonvalid, i, max;

    nonvalid = [];

    if (arr.length !== 0) {
        max = arr[0];

        for (i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] < max) {
                nonvalid.push(arr[i]);
            } else {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return nonvalid;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not [compare with the last known good number](http://jsfiddle.net/8CzxM/)?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 10, 5, 11, 12, 2, 4, 25],
    nonvalid = [],
    lastGoodValue = 0;

for (var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (j && arr[j] <= lastGoodValue) {
        //if not the first number and is less than the last good value
        nonvalid.push(arr[j]);
    } else {
        //if first number or a good value
        lastGoodValue = arr[j];
    }
}

console.log(arr, nonvalid)
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25xYb/)**</kbd>

```
var arr = [24398, 24397, 25004, 25177, 26302, 28036, 29312, 29635, 29829, 30476, 32595, 33732, 34995, 36047, 36363, 37310, 38022, 38882, 40746, 41212, 42846, 43588, 44029, 44595, 44846, 45727, 46041, 47293, 48002, 48930, 49858, 51184, 51560, 53895, 54247, 54614, 55713, 56813, 57282, 57480, 57875, 58073, 58403, 60321, 61469, 62051, 62310, 62634, 63217, 64505, 65413, 65677, 65940, 66203, 66572, 67957, 68796, 68964, 69098, 69233, 69435, 69759, 71496, 72577, 72823, 73007, 73252, 73743, 73866, 76405, 77037, 77416, 77669, 79691, 80885, 81339, 81794, 82067, 82431, 83244, 84861, 86836, 88632, 89877, 90296, 91049, 91885, 92351, 92614, 93141, 93733, 93930, 94531, 95206, 95882, 96895, 97732, 97973, 99261, 99422, 99583, 100332, 100599, 101666, 102066, 102600, 103504, 104432, 105174, 107216, 109085, 110181, 110679, 111177, 111988, 112553, 113005, 113457, 600, 600],
    nonvalid = [],
    max = arr[0];

for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
    var test= arr[j+1]<=max ? nonvalid.push(arr[j+1]) : max=arr[j];
}

alert(nonvalid); // 24397, 600, 600
```

Comment: So correct! Thanks for answering and sharing this! The +1 in array key was just missing.

Comment: @Ricardus you're welcome!! This was a quite interesting question! +1'd

Answer (score 1):

a simple functional way to do it inline without loops or variables:

```
arr.filter(function(a,b,c){
  return  Math.max.apply(Math, c.slice(0,b)) > a ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` with this example:

```js
const ascendingArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const descendingArray = [1,2,3,7,5,6,4]

const isAscending = array => array.map((a, i) => a > array[i + 1]).indexOf(true) === -1

console.log(isAscending(descendingArray)); // should be false
console.log(isAscending(ascendingArray)); // should be true
```

Or, you can use `filter` with this example:

```js
const ascendingArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const descendingArray = [1,2,3,7,5,6,4]

const isAscending = array => array.filter((a, i) => a > array[i + 1]).length === 0;

console.log(isAscending(ascendingArray)); // should be true
console.log(isAscending(descendingArray)); // should be false
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the array first, remove any element that is not in order with `array.splice(index, 1)`, and continue.  That way, any element must by greater than the one right before it, but the one right before it will always be the max.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after taking your advices I tried the following algorightm. It seems to do its job but its a bit overkill.

> for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
>
> ```
> for (var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
>
>     if ( arr[j] > 0 && arr[i] > 0 && j != i ){
>
>         if ( arr[j] <= arr[i] && j > i ){
>
>             if ( jQuery.inArray(j, nonvalid) == - 1) nonvalid.push(j);
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```